# How to set the path for jdk on linux 2.6.33-r2?

Tags: linux, java

I have downloaded jdk7 from "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html" and was trying to install it on linux platform (my OS is linux 2.6.33-gentoo-r2). I have done untar intially, then it created jdk1.7.0 folder. Can you please tell me how to set the path for jdk?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a java question. Actually on linux you have to modify path in your login script. For example on my system where I use bash the file is `.bash_profile` and it is under my home directory.

So, edit this file. First define JAVA_HOME:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0
```

Then use JAVA_HOME variable in PATH definition:

```
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

do not forget to export both:

```
export PATH
export JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Doesn't the PATH have to be set to $JAVA_HOME/bin versus just $JAVA_HOME? Or does $JAVA_HOME work and the OS will automatically add bin?

Comment: You need $JAVA_HOME/bin in your $PATH